# Why is $#a one less than the actual number of elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl

Does anyone knows why `$#a` one less than the actually number of elements in an array?

```
$ perl -we '@a=(1,2);print $#a'
1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the index of the last item and since arrays start at zero (unless you're messing around with things that are better left alone), `$#a` is one less than the length of the array.

Comment: Arrays start at `$[`, which can be changed if you are brave. `perl -e '$[=10;@a=(foo);print $#a'` ==> 10

Comment: @mob: `$[` is something best left alone unless you're a hateful person that wants to make the people maintaining your code suffer and curse Perl.

Comment: @mob: [it is deprecated](https://metacpan.org/module/perlvar#Deprecated-and-removed-variables) so it may disappear any time (5.16?); just forget it :)

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Sometimes I get "brave" and "misanthropic" mixed-up.

Answer (score 11):

I would imagine that is because it is the index of the last element in the array.  Since the array indexing begins at 0, you need to add one to get the total number of elements in an array.

NB:  You can also do this to find the count of an array:

```
@arr = ("one", "two");
$count =  @arr;
print $count;
```

Comment: Indeed. Use `scalar @a` if you want a count.

Comment: Yes, I nearly forgot to mention that!  Thanks.  Have updated my answer with a short example :)

Comment: @Quentin, I prefer `0+@a` over `scalar(@a)` when something other than just `@a` is required. It's a little more indicative of what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Array `@a = ("a","b","c");`

Value of $#a = index of last element(=2).

`$a[0] = "a";`
`$a[1] = "b";`
`$a[2] = "c";`

if you want to get number of elements in the array, you can assign the array to a scalar
like

`$arrayLength = @a;` #(=3)

Hope this helps you

Comment: In other words, in scalar context `@a` is the number of elements. Try for example: `perl -we '@a=(1,2);printf "%d,%d\n",$#a,scalar(@a)'`

Answer (score 2):

`$#array` is used to find the index of the last element in the array.

In the example above it is position 1 - as indexes in arrays start at 0 in perl.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is telling you *what* it returns (which you already know), but you asked *why* it returns what it does.

Unfortunately, it's not really possible to answer *why* it returns what it does. Maybe because it makes the following easier?

```
for (0..$#a) {
   ...
}
```